# Upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.3.7

Tags: magento2.2, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I tried to upgrade Magento from 2.2.4 to 2.3.7
This is what i tried

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

I got this errors

```
 Problem 1
- magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping[2.0.0].
- temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 requires temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0].
- temando/module-shipping 2.0.0 requires temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-remover[1.0.0].
- don't install temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0|remove magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1
- don't install temando/module-shipping-remover 1.0.0|remove magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1
- Installation request for magento/project-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[2.2.1].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.7].
```

So i tried to change version in composer.json in the global scope

```
"version": "2.3.7",
```

Composer update

Now i got those errors

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7
- Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.2
- Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.2
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.7].
- Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.1
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7 requires laminas/laminas-mail ^2.9.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-mail[2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.10.2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.2, 2.12.3, 2.12.4, 2.12.5, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.9.0].
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.10.0
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.10.1
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.10.2
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.11.0
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.11.1
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.0
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.1
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.2
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.3
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.4
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.12.5
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.13.0
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.13.1
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.14.0
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.14.1
- don't install zendframework/zend-mail 2.6.0|don't install laminas/laminas-mail 2.9.0
- Installation request for zendframework/zend-mail ~2.6.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-mail[2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2].
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps:

1. Remove vendor/*
2. Remove composer.lock
3. Modify composer.json with your target Magento version

Run **composer update**

[More Detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: Thanks, it installed dependancies but in the end i got error  [InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  Package is not installed: magento/project-community-edition-2.3.7.0 do you have if the update is succeeded or not?

Comment: I think you need to modify composer.json, that is old. Compare 2.24 and 2.3.7, then modify. Specially: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/composer.json#L130

Comment: Also, you can try using composer version 1, not 2.

Comment: Here is sol: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29997#issuecomment-849018040

Comment: I have changed composer.json and  mixe it by new and old version the composer seems working now i got this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in /home/wetag/public_html/vendor/cart2quote/module-features/registration.php:7
What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I did upgrade 2.3.4 to 2.3.7 just some day ago via below commands.  hope it works for you.

> *)set developer mode
>
> 1. php -d memory_limit=6G bin/magento maintenance:enable
> 2. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7
>    --no-update
> 3. composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0
>    friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10
>    pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0
>    squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update 4) composer remove --dev
>    sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
> 4. composer update or upload composer.phar in root and run php -d
>    memory_limit=6G composer.phar update
> 5. rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/*
>    pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*
> 6. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> 7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> 8. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> 9. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> 10. php bin/magento cache:clean
> 11. php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:
>
> 13. php bin/magento --version
> 14. php bin/magento maintenance:disable
> 15. Php version set 7.4 via cpanel or htaccess

Comment: can you share your initial composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `--ignore-platform-reqs=>1` after your command.

Comment: i've already done composer update --ignore-platform-reqs